# How do I modify an oracle.sql.ARRAY argument in a Java stored procedure?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

When writing Java stored procedures, I often *receive* values via `oracle.sql.ARRAY` parameters. However, how do I *export* values via `oracle.sql.ARRAY` parameters? For example:

```
public static void fetchFavoriteFoods(oracle.sql.ARRAY favoriteFoods) {
    // What must be done here to add "pizza" and "cheese burger" to favoriteFoods?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you don't.
[`java.sql.Array`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html) and its implementations (like `oracle.sql.ARRAY`) are

> a logical pointer to the data in the
>   SQL ARRAY value rather than containing
>   the ARRAY value's data.

Needless to say, this means that they are read-only values.

Answer (score 0):

This should be along the lines of what you are looking for:
[Oracle ARRAY type usage](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A81042_01/DOC/java.816/a81354/oraarr3.htm#1040124)

Basically, you can create an object of your own oracle.sql.ARRAY and use it.